# Как сделать круглыми углы блоков div без картинок?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать круглыми углы блоков div без картинок?

Comment: [http://border-radius.com](http://border-radius.com)

Answer (score 5):

```
.rounded-corners {
      -moz-border-radius: 10px; /* Firefox */
      -webkit-border-radius: 10px; /* Safari, Chrome */
      border-radius: 10px; /* CSS3 */
      behavior: url(PIE.htc); /* IE < 9 */
}
```

Скачать PIE.htc можно [здесь](http://css3pie.com/)

Answer (score 2):

css:

```
    .ololo{
            background:#222222
            -moz-border-radius: 20px; 
            -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
        }
```

---

html:

```
    <div class="ololo"> olololo </div>
```

Comment: Забыли просто border-ratius: 20px;

Answer (score 2):

[Генератор Блоков](http://css3.mikeplate.com/), Круглые + тени, вообщем можно сделать очень красивые див блоки.

Answer (score 2):

Можно написать так

```
-moz-border-radius: 10px; /* Firefox */
-webkit-border-radius: 10px; /* Safari, Chrome */
border-radius: 10px; /* CSS3 */
```

А потом подключить [библиотеку](http://modernizr.com/) для html5 и css3

Answer (score 0):

На данный момент (осень 2016) [92.74% всех браузеров в мире поддерживают непрефиксную форму свойства](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius). И, если вам не требуется поддержка IE8 и меньше, можно смело писать вот так:

```
.class {
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```